# How to manage opacity of element INSIDE table row on HOVER this row?

Tags: html, css, html-table, hover

I want to make on my simple site next feature. I have table where data is placed.

```
<tr><td>some data<label>edit</label> <label>delete</label></td><td>some data</td></tr>
```

I want next: Text in label is invisible normally, but when I hover TABLE ROW (not label exactly) all labels in this row become visible.

I know how to do this on HOVER LABEL (all what I need it to add style for `table > tbody > tr> td > label : hover` and style for same, but without `hover`), but what I have to do to make this feature?

**update (solved):**
css:

```
.table tbody > tr > td label{
    opacity: 0;
}

.table tbody > tr > td:hover  label{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Post the CSS you have tried

Comment: :) its very simple. I will edit question in a few seconds.

Comment: Huh. Fast. Sry, can't do anything for you :( don't have enought repo. Ty very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/WLEXS/)

```
.table tbody > tr > td:hover > label{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: @SharikovVladislav If you want the effect when hovering over the *row* instead of the cell, as your question appears to suggest, then you will want to move the :hover pseudo class from the td to the tr selector.

Comment: @pwdst, rly you are right. I was thinking about it yesterday, but forget it now. Thank you, good point.